# subnetworks in the following diagram

Tags: subnet, network-core, network

I know that routers are used to divide the networks but i am confused to check the number of networks in the following diagram. Does the switches that are in the green color is a seperate subnetwork? or they belong to the same subnetwork of network marked in red color? please help thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that we do not deal with VLAN that adds a layer in the graph, but with a basic configuration (no sub interface, ...) the red area is related to a single subnetwork/network. In fact the right term is broadcast domain (and not sub/network).
That is the switch (I mean L2 only switch) is not aware of IP addresses and the switch is achieved by only looking at the ethernet header (ie. a map between the destination MAC addresse and the outgoing interface).

Therefore, considering the figure you provided and the captions (core, distribution, access) that seems to define a network hierarchy, the left interface of the "core" router may has a configured IP address (eg. 192.168.1.1/24) and all computers/servers directly connected to the switches in the red area (connected to the left interface of router) will belong to the same subnet (192.168.1.0/24).

Answer (score 1):

I think the subnets are marked as a grey color on the picture because they are part of different networks connected to different router interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Those switches may be used for end users access on different buildings the complete architecture should be :

Servers ==access switches==aggr switches==Core layer==aggr switches==access switches==end users

This type of design is adopted in medium/large networks